# No match for 'operator==' in function

Tags: c++, arrays, string, operator-keyword, caesar-cipher

I am working on a caesar decipher project, and in the CaesarDecipher function I keep getting this error when compiling:

> error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘textInit.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, >_Alloc>::operator[] [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, _Alloc >= std::allocator](((long unsigned int)i)) == alphabet[j]’

Here is the code for that function:

```
string CipherMessage::CaesarDecipher(string key)
{
  int keyValue;
  int charValue;
  string textInit = m_text;
  string textFinal;
  // Initializes an array containing the alphabet. A=index 0, B=index 1, etc
  string alphabet[26] = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","\
O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};

  for (int i=0; i<=25; i++){
    if (alphabet[i] == key)
      keyValue = i;
  }
for (int i=0; i<=textInit.length(); i++){
    for (int j=0; j<=25; j++){
      if (textInit[i] == alphabet[j])   // Error occurs here
        charValue = j;
    }
    charValue = (charValue+keyValue)%26;
    for (int j=0; j<=25; j++){
      if (charValue == j)
        textFinal += alphabet[j];
    }
  }
  cout << "Final " << textFinal << endl;

  return textFinal;
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You cannot compare a `std::string` with a single `char`.

Comment: (obligatory [reference link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp))

Comment: What do you mean?  I don't have anything of char type.  I am comparing a single letter in the string with a single letter in the array.

Comment: @MichaelDaugherty _"I am comparing a single letter in the string with a single letter in the array."_ You don't. Double check it!

Comment: First thing I noticed was the for loop, maybe wanted: `for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) { `

Comment: @MichaelDaugherty `string alphabet[26]` are 26 full strings. Use `string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";`

Comment: I iterate over the string textInit and checking if textInit[i] matches each term in alphabet.  Is my iteration over the string wrong?

Comment: @MichaelDaugherty The loop over textInit is not wrong, but the variable alphabet is.

Comment: @MichaelDaugherty Your conception what makes up a _single letter_ is wrong.

Comment: @Michael: You *do* have something of `char` type: `textInit[i]`.

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant to declare `alphabet` like

```
string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

to get rid of this error message.

As mentioned in a comment you declared an array of 26 full fledged `string`s instead, but indexing from `textInit[i]` actually returns you a `char` type (which cannot be compared to a `std::string` reasonably in turn).

Comment: Or even better, `static const char alphabet[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";`

Comment: Good point. But I'd like to avoid confusing the OP even more at this point.

Comment: It's okay, I understand it now!  I was completely missing your point  πάντα ῥεῖ

Answer (score 1):

The error means you are trying to compare two different types and there is no defined equality operator for those two types.

You mentioned this line in particular is at fault:

```
if (textInit[i] == alphabet[j])
```

What is the type of textInit and the type of alphabet? Look at your declarations:

```
// textInit is a string
string textInit = m_text;

// alphabet is an array of strings
string alphabet[26] ={"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","\
O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
```

Indexing into a string like **textInit** returns a **char&** (a character reference).
Indexing into an array of strings like **alphabet** returns a **string**.

So when you're comparing textInit[i] to alphabet[j]), you're trying to compare a string against a char&. There is no defined way to compare the two, so the program fails to compile.

As others have mentioned, one quick fix is to change alphabets declaration to:

```
// note that single quotes ('') are used for characters while double quotes "" are used for strings
char alphabet[26] ={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
```

Now alphabet is an array of characters, and indexing into alphabet returns a char (a character). So the line:

```
if (textInit[i] == alphabet[j])
```

is now okay because you're comparing a char to a char&, and the types are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of error is that the types textInit[i] and alphabet[j] are not match.
You can change string alphabet[26] to char alphabet[26].

Comment: _"You can change string alphabet[26] to char alphabet[26]."_ Not without changing the initialization.

Answer (score 0):

These other answers do solve your problem, but there's a different solution: instead of iterating over the alphabet, you can do this check in constant time by using the nature of the char type. Characters are just integers, and the letters (of a given case) are guaranteed to be in order consecutively. So you can replace the first loop with this:

```
if (textInit[i] >= 'A' && textInit[i] <= 'Z') {
    charValue = textInit[i] - 'A';
}
```

And that second loop is also unnecessary. It can just be this:

```
textFinal += (charValue + 'A');
```